# CRM 2011 : getting the view count over Articles

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011

In CRM 2011, what is a way in which I can know how many times my KBase Article is being viewed? I need to show it in some page as to how many views does each of my article hold.

Comment: My team leader suggests to use IIS Logs

Comment: 2011 provides no such thing oob. I'd try a "counter" plugin on retrieve, the same as it would be for any other entity.

Comment: Thank you Alex, i think i will try this way